# What kind of hinges?

Tags: wood, doors

I'm want to hange a privacy lattice in my carport. Dimensions are 8x8 feet, not including the 2x4's. The structure will be pretty heavy. Load will be supported from top by hinges in a 4x4. What's the cheapest/best option?

Answer (score 2):

Use heavy screw eyes or eye bolts, screwed into the 2x4 frame of the lattice panel, and screw hooks or screw bolts into the 4x4.

Comment: That's exactly what I was think! But I'm not sure how to secure from accidental detachment. I'm thinking of threading a few hooks, but this still seems iffy.

Comment: If you use eye bolts on at least one portion of the assembly and hooks on the other, point the hooks in opposite directions and accidental detachment isn't likely. Threaded devices for at least one portion allows the use of lag type devices for the other, otherwise assembly is not possible or at least not easily accomplished.

Comment: This works wonderfully! All hooks and eyebolts paired in the same direction, secured by cane bolts at bottom, weight of assembly makes accidental detachment highly unlikely. Easy to remove and install with two people. Would post a pic if I knew how. Thanks guys!